# OCMockito: verify that a method of a mock is called sometime in the future

Tags: ios, unit-testing, ocmockito

First I mock an object.
Then I do something that should make the object's certain method be called. The call is asynchronous.

So what I'd like to verify is: in at most 5 seconds, this method of the mock object should be called.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OCMockito doesn't support asynchronous verification (yet). Until it does, I'd recommend using a hand-rolled mock instead, and OCHamcrest's `assertWithTimeout`.

For example, here's a hand-rolled mock to confirm that `fooBar` was called:

```
@interface MockFoo : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL fooBarWasCalled;
- (void)fooBar;
@end

@implementation MockFoo

- (void)fooBar
{
    self.fooBarWasCalled = YES;
}

@end
```

Then with OCHamcrest:

```
assertWithTimeout(5, thatEventually(@(myMock.fooBarWasCalled), isTrue());
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, I've thought about this, but I didn't find a way to turn mockito's verify() into something like a bool value which can be asserted, anything I've been missing?

Comment: I've added a simple example.